# Autocomplete REST API, looking for Shanghai, Beijing

Tags: autocomplete, here-api

I've got wrong responses when looking for Shanghai or Beijing. See my tests below. With other capitals it works fine: Berlin, Tokyo, Moscow. Also, if I look in wego.here.com I get the right response.

Could you help?

Thank you,
Sorin

http://autocomplete.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id=&country=&query=Beijing

**Shanghai, Beijing wrong, no matchLevel:state, no matchLevelCity**

{"suggestions":[{"label":"Philippines, Calamba, Beijing","language":"en","countryCode":"PHL","locationId":"NT_oqMNKjEk.to1mdjm1gqqPA","address":{"country":"Philippines","state":"Calabarzon","county":"Laguna","city":"Calamba","district":"Punta","street":"Beijing","postalCode":"4027"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Namibia, Khomasdal North, Beijing St","language":"en","countryCode":"NAM","locationId":"NT_Qm6w1xeYD4hjpEhSnRneMD","address":{"country":"Namibia","state":"Khomas","county":"Windhoek","city":"Khomasdal North","street":"Beijing St"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Kenya, Machakos, Beijing Rd","language":"en","countryCode":"KEN","locationId":"NT_7VHT8XcIyTZGeBjQbS8gLD","address":{"country":"Kenya","county":"Machakos","city":"Machakos","district":"Mlolongo","street":"Beijing Rd"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Philippines, Mabalacat, Beijing","language":"en","countryCode":"PHL","locationId":"NT_PxBKm2mHErRett02lDJMtD","address":{"country":"Philippines","state":"Central Luzon","county":"Pampanga","city":"Mabalacat","district":"Macapagal Village","street":"Beijing","postalCode":"2010"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Philippines, Dasmariñas, Beijing","language":"en","countryCode":"PHL","locationId":"NT_DQA9lrPzLnQFHFOuF1AzuD","address":{"country":"Philippines","state":"Calabarzon","county":"Cavite","city":"Dasmariñas","district":"Paliparan III","street":"Beijing","postalCode":"4114"},"matchLevel":"street"}]}

Test on:
[wego.here.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raA4U.png)

**Berlin: corect**

{"suggestions":[{"label":"Deutschland, Frankfurt am Main, Berliner Straße","language":"de","countryCode":"DEU","locationId":"NT_OV3A4F7PVZMW36XQixpFiB","address":{"country":"Deutschland","state":"Hessen","county":"Frankfurt am Main","city":"Frankfurt am Main","district":"Altstadt","street":"Berliner Straße","postalCode":"60311"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Deutschland, Berlin, Berlin, Berlin","language":"de","countryCode":"DEU","locationId":"NT_DKX2wfaWICS7JyfHmCOJhB","address":{"**country":"Deutschland","state":"Berlin","county":"Berlin","city":"Berlin"**,"postalCode":"10117"},"matchLevel":"city"},{"label":"Deutschland, Berlin, Berlin","language":"de","countryCode":"DEU","locationId":"NT_MA6xiXs5hGsq-tRm65Wf-A","address":{"country":"Deutschland","state":"Berlin","county":"Berlin"},"matchLevel":"county"},{"label":"Deutschland, Berlin","language":"de","countryCode":"DEU","locationId":"NT_yGnW7rZT3HnFM0EL.MXf8D","address":{"country":"Deutschland","state":"Berlin"},"matchLevel":"state"},{"label":"Sverige, Torsåker, Berlins väg","language":"sv","countryCode":"SWE","locationId":"NT_6X3gCwjX1ksmmBqNs4kezC","address":{"country":"Sverige","state":"Gävleborgs län","county":"Hofors","city":"Torsåker","street":"Berlins väg","postalCode":"813 40"},"matchLevel":"street"}]}

**Tokyo corect:**

{"suggestions":[{"label":"Japan, Tokyo","language":"en","countryCode":"JPN","locationId":"NT_oRZz9aPaSYfbouvvHbUGpA","address":{**"country":"Japan","county":"Japan","city":"Tokyo"},"matchLevel":"city"**},{"label":"Philippines, Imus, Tokyo St","language":"en","countryCode":"PHL","locationId":"NT_NAxCJnorfvgKjS8ZsXcdhD","address":{"country":"Philippines","state":"Calabarzon","county":"Cavite","city":"Imus","district":"Malagasang II-G","street":"Tokyo St","postalCode":"4103"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Philippines, Binangonan, Tokyo","language":"en","countryCode":"PHL","locationId":"NT_ZnBPiug1PQcQ--saSfcdvB","address":{"country":"Philippines","state":"Calabarzon","county":"Rizal","city":"Binangonan","district":"Tayuman","street":"Tokyo","postalCode":"1940"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Argentina, Hurlingham, Tokyo","language":"es","countryCode":"ARG","locationId":"NT_m8XDPlatLYzVnvzuOHVEQD","address":{"country":"Argentina","state":"Buenos Aires","county":"Hurlingham","city":"Hurlingham","street":"Tokyo","postalCode":"1686"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Nederland, IJsselstein, Tokyostraat","language":"nl","countryCode":"NLD","locationId":"NT_G.9gnZd1wDFJgrhzyPW0rC","address":{"country":"Nederland","state":"Utrecht","county":"IJsselstein","city":"IJsselstein","street":"Tokyostraat","postalCode":"3404 DW"},"matchLevel":"street"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detailed China map supported only for requests inside China.
Detailed information about coverage can be found by link https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/coverage-geocoder.html

Comment: Hi Artem,

The link you have sent explains that for geocoding Outside China someone must use an "Entry Map Content" .  I am not using the Geocoding but the Autocomplete API.  Is it possible to use an “Entry Map Content” in  Autocomplete and how?


Thank you,
Sorin

Comment: Autocomplete is part of geocoding. You can see it even from URL. You are already using entry map. Entry map means that there are no data, no roads, nothing. For example, try this coordinate 22.60779, 114.0331 on wego.here.com, it will show you a place in the middle of nowhere. If you want to have access to detailed Chine map data, then you request should be originated from Chinese ip address.